# set a CPT as parent of a page

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical

I have a custom post type called `Event` which is registered like this:

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_post_types');

function register_custom_post_types() {
   $event_capabilities = array(
      'publish_posts' => 'publish_events',
      'edit_posts' => 'edit_events',
      'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_event',
      'delete_posts' => 'delete_events',
      'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_events',
      'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_events',
      'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_events',
      'edit_post' => 'edit_event',
      'delete_post' => 'delete_event',
      'read_post' => 'read_event',
   );
   register_post_type('event',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Event' )
         ),
        'rewrite' => 'event',
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_position' => 8,
        'capability_type' => array('event', 'events'),
        'capabilities' => $event_capabilities,
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
   );
}
```

I would like to be able to set an event as the parent of a ordinary page. In other words I would like all my events to show up in the `Parent` select element under the `Page Attributes`.

I have read many posts on how to set a CPT as the child of a page, but not the other way around.

Comment: See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783231/wordpress-custom-post-type-cannot-access-child-page/26793712#26793712) In my previous answer I didn't use the same naming conventions as you cited above but the subject matter was nearly identical.

Comment: Be aware: `$event_capabilities` is already an array and later you are writing "`'capabilities' => array($event_capabilities)` instead of `'capabilities' => $event_capabilities`. Weren't you getting an "illegal offset type" warning?

Comment: I did the same thing on a few occasions.. Gimme some time and I'll post a working solution.

Comment: @Abhik - That would be really nice.

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam - No I did not get any warnings and changing the code did not change the behavior, but still thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge we try to take on here is how to:

- not remove or replace the current *Page Attribute* meta box
- keep the hierarchical information in the drop-down.

We assume we're on the single page edit screen, and want to add the `event` post type to the `page` *parent drop-down*.

The drop-down is displayed using the `wp_dropdown_pages()` function, that calls the `get_pages()` function. It only supports a single post type.

Here are two ways to do this:

### Method #1 - Modify SQL

*Here's an experimental way, since it deals with SQL modifications.*

Since there's no obvious way to filter the generated SQL query in `get_pages()`, we can use the general `query` filter to our needs.

To make the dropdown more user friendly, when it contains titles from multiple post types, we use the `list_pages` filter, to prepend the post type info.

**Example:**

So instead of displaying the options like:

```
"(no parent)"
"About the Music Hall"
    "History"
    "Location"
"Concerts"
    "Of Monsters and Men"
    "Vienna Philharmonic Orchestra"
"Tickets"
```

we get:

```
"(no parent)"
"page - About the Music Hall"
    "page  - History" 
    "page  - Location"
"event - Concerts"
    "event - Of Monsters and Men"
    "event - Vienna Philharmonic Orchestra"
"page - Tickets"
```

**Demo plugin:**

Here's the code snippet that could be placed in a plugin for testing:

```
/**
 * Add the hierarchical 'event' post type, to the 'page' parent drop-down.
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204439/26350
 */ 
is_admin() && add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', function( $dropdown_args, $post )
{
     // Only do this for the 'page' post type on the single edit 'page' screen
     if( 'page' === get_current_screen()->id && 'page' === $post->post_type )
     {
        // Modify the options' titles
        add_filter( 'list_pages', 'wpse_add_post_type_info_in_options', 10, 2 );

        // Modify the get_pages() query
        add_filter( 'query', function( $sql )
        {
            // Only run this once
            if( ! did_action( 'wpse_change_cpt' ) )
            {
                do_action( 'wpse_change_cpt' );

                // Adjust the post type part of the query - add the 'event' post type
                $sql = str_replace( 
                    "post_type = 'page' ", 
                    "post_type IN ( 'event', 'page' ) ", 
                    $sql 
                );
            }
            return $sql;
        } );
    }
    return $dropdown_args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

where:

```
function wpse_add_post_type_info_in_options ( $title, $page )
{
    return $page->post_type . ' - ' . $title;
}
```

and a little bit of clean up:

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_pages', function( $output )
{
    if( did_action( 'wpse_change_cpt' ) )
        remove_filter( 'list_pages', 'wpse_add_post_type_info_in_options', 10, 2 );

    return $output;
} );
```

### Method #2 - Only use `wp_dropdown_pages()`

Here we let`wp_dropdown_pages()` run  twice and then merge it into a single drop-down; once for the `page` post type and again for the `event` post type:

```
/**
 * Add the hierarchical 'event' post type, to the 'page' parent drop-down.
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204439/26350
 */ 
is_admin() && add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'wpse_attributes', 99, 2 );

function wpse_attributes( $dropdown_args, $post )
{
    // Run this filter callback only once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 99 );

    // Only do this for the 'page' post type on the edit page screen
    if( 'page' === get_current_screen()->id && 'page' === $post->post_type )
    {
        // Modify the input arguments, for the 'event' drop-down
        $modified_args = $dropdown_args;
        $modified_args['post_type'] = 'page';
        $modified_args['show_option_no_change'] = __( '=== Select Events here below: ===' );            
        $modified_args['show_option_none'] = false;

        // Add the 'event' drop-down
        add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_pages', function( $output ) use ( $modified_args )
        {
            // Only run it once
            if( ! did_action( 'wpse_dropdown' ) )
            {
                do_action( 'wpse_dropdown' );

                // Create our second drop-down for events
                $output .= wp_dropdown_pages( $modified_args );

                // Adjust the output, so we only got a single drop-down
                $output = str_replace( 
                    [ "<select name='parent_id' id='parent_id'>", "</select>"],
                    '', 
                    $output 
                );
                $output = "<select name='parent_id' id='parent_id'>" . $output . "</select>";
            }
            return $output;
        } );
    }
    return $dropdown_args;
}
```

Here the two hierarchical drop-downs are separated by the empty *=== Select Events here below: ===* option.

**Example:**

```
"(no parent)"
"About the Music Hall"
    "History"
    "Location"
"Tickets"
"=== Select Events here below: ==="
"Concerts"
    "Of Monsters and Men"
    "Vienna Philharmonic Orchestra"
```

### Adjusting the main query

Assume now that we create a page called *Of Monsters And Men - Info* with the `omam-info` slug and select the event *Of Monsters And Men* as the parent, with the `omam` slug.

Then the path would be

```
example.tld/omam/omam-info
```

but this gives a 404 error. The reason is that the `get_page_path()` check inside the `\WP_Query` class, for the main query, fails:

```
if ( '' != $qv['pagename'] ) {
    $this->queried_object = get_page_by_path($qv['pagename']);
    if ( !empty($this->queried_object) )
        $this->queried_object_id = (int) $this->queried_object->ID;
    else
        unset($this->queried_object);
```

This is because here `get_page_by_path()` only checks for the `page` and `attachment` post types, not the `event` post type. Unfortunately there's no explicit filter to change that.

We could of course use the `query` filter, like we did above, but let's try another workaround.

We can try to adjust the un-assigned properties `queried_object_id` and `queried_object_id` of the `\WP_Query` object with:

```
/**
 * Support for page slugs with any kind event parent hierarchy
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204439/26350
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( 
            ! is_admin()               // Front-end only
        &&  $q->is_main_query()        // Target the main query
        &&  $q->get( 'pagename' )      // Check for pagename query variable
        &&  ! $q->get( 'post_type' )   // Target the 'page' post type
        && $page = get_page_by_path( $q->get( 'pagename' ), OBJECT, [ 'page', 'event', 'attachment' ] ) 
    ) {
        if( is_a( $page, '\WP_Post' ) )
        {                
            $q->queried_object_id = $page->ID;
            $q->queried_object = $page;
        }
    }
} );
```

This should also support any number of event parents, like the following hierarchy:

```
ecample.tld/event-grandparent/event-parent/event-child/page-slug
```

### Note

For the parent drop-downs in the `edit.php` screen, we might use the `quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args` filter, instead of the `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` filter we used above.

Comment: I haven't yet tried out your solution, but it seems very promising. Think this will be an answer that other people really will find useful if they looking for the same thing.

Comment: Hopefully this can be of any use, but it would be easier if `get_pages()` would support multiple post types ;-) @Cyclone

Comment: I'm now adding support to link my cpt as a parent using your second method, which works fine. The strange thing is that I now get a 404 when trying to access a page that is linked this way. My guess would be that this has something to do with the rewrite rule for the cpt?

Comment: Yes the `get_page_path()` check is most likely the reason for your 404. So you should try out the extra code in the "Adjusting the main query" part of the answer. [Here's another question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/204729/26350) that's somewhat related, where we work around the limitations of the `get_page_path()` check too. @Cyclone

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that you had updated your answer. Thank you very much, I'm convinced that this will work.

Comment: I tried to add the `pre_get_posts()` code, but it does not seem to work as expected. I still receives a 404 and when I try to debugging `$q->get("pagename");` always returns null, when I'm visiting a page linked to an event as a parent. Another strange thing is that I'm using ` get_post_permalink($post->ID)` to display the links to my subpage and these are always printed as `example.com?page_type=page&p=<ID>` even since it should be a nice url?

Comment: Also if I dump the `WP_Query` object inside the hook, the `query => attachements` and `query_vars => attachment` are set to the slug of the page, while `query_vars => pagename` isn't set at all.

Comment: This works on my vanilla install, where I get the `pagename` query variable for a page with an event parent. Works also for hierarchy of event parents. Not sure if you got some attachments with the same slug that are interfering in similar way as [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/204729/26350) ? @Cyclone

Comment: I tried on a vanilla installtion and I have the same problem. Perhaps it has something to do with how the permalinks are set up, what is your configuration? What wp version are you running?

Comment: It also seems like the reason for this is because `get_page_by_path()` is called earlier with only 'page` as the post type, which in turn sets `attachment` in query vars. If I change the code directly in `get_page_by_path()` to always include the `event` post type, then it works as expected. I'm thinking that this **may** have something to do with how you actually register your custom post type?

Comment: It works if I use the `request` filter and replaces `post_type IN ('page','attachment')` with `post_type IN ('page','attachment','event')`

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt, you need to remove the core **Page Attributes** Meta Box, then add your own keeping everything intact except altering the parent post type. Here are my codes, tweaked to work with your `events` post type. Tried to make it copy/paste ready, however, if you encounter errors, please let me know.

```
/* Remove the core Page Attribute Metabox */
function event_remove_pa_meta_boxes() {
  remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', 'page', 'side' );
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'event_remove_pa_meta_boxes' );

/* Set the Page Attribute Metabox again*/
function events_pa_meta_box( $post ) {

    add_meta_box(
        'event-select',
        __( 'Page Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
        'events_selectors_box',
        'page',
        'side',
        'core'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'events_pa_meta_box' );

/* Recreate the meta box. */
function events_selectors_box( $post ) {

    /* Set Events as Post Parent */
    $parents = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'   => 'event', 
            'orderby'     => 'title', 
            'order'       => 'ASC', 
            'numberposts' => -1 
        )
    );

    echo '<p><strong>Parent</strong></p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="parent_id">Parent</label>';
    if ( !empty( $parents ) ) {

        echo '<select id="parent_id" name="parent_id">';

        foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
            printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', esc_attr( $parent->ID ), selected( $parent->ID, $post->post_parent, false ), esc_html( $parent->post_title ) );
        }

        echo '</select>';

    } else {

        echo '<p>Please <a href="' . admin_url( "post-new.php?post_type=event" ) . '">create an event first</a>.</p>';

    }

    /* Page Templates */

    if ( 'page' == $post->post_type && 0 != count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID ) {

        $template = !empty($post->page_template) ? $post->page_template : false;

        echo '<p><strong>Template</strong></p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="page_template">Page Template</label>';

        echo '<select id="page_template" name="page_template">';

        $default_title = apply_filters( 'default_page_template_title',  __( 'Default Template' ), 'meta-box' );

        echo '<option value="default">' . esc_html( $default_title ) . '</option>'      

            page_template_dropdown($template);

        echo '</select>';

    }

    /* Page Order */
    echo '<p><strong>' . _e('Order') .'</strong></p>';

    echo '<label class="screen-reader-text" for="menu_order">'. _e('Order') . '</label><input name="menu_order" type="text" size="4" id="menu_order" value="'. esc_attr($post->menu_order) .'" />';

    /* Help Paragraph */
    if ( 'page' == $post->post_type && get_current_screen()->get_help_tabs() ) { ?>
        echo '<p>' . _e( 'Need help? Use the Help tab in the upper right of your screen.' ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Just noticed that there's filter available to modify the default args in page attribute meta box:

```
$dropdown_args = array(
    'post_type'        => $post->post_type,
    'exclude_tree'     => $post->ID,
    'selected'         => $post->post_parent,
    'name'             => 'parent_id',
    'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'),
    'sort_column'      => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'echo'             => 0,
);

$dropdown_args = apply_filters( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', $dropdown_args, $post );
```

So, there could be a super easy way to do what you want.